# Ordered list items are not correclty updating to the appropriate step number

Tags: html, internet-explorer

```
<ol type="1">
 <div style="margin: 1em 0; margin-left: 45px;">
  <li>
   <div style="margin-top: 5px;"> 
     Div Both before and after Li..... voima
   </div>
  </li>
 </div>
 <div style="margin: 1em 0; margin-left: 45px;">
  <li>
   <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
    rohkeus
   </div>
  </li>
 </div>
 <div style="margin: 1em 0; margin-left: 45px;">
  <li>
   <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
    uskomus
   </div>
  </li>
 </div>
</ol>
```

If the above ol(ordered list) is displayed in IE8 then we obtain a list with a non incrementing list numbers ........ how can i get the correct list numbers without removing the div tags
Does anyone have an idea and suggest an alternate way of doing it.

Note: the List correct numbering if we make tick compatibility View and is also working find in IE6 and IE7 and Mozilla firefox 3.6 and the problem is only in non Compatibility View In IE8

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to add numbers to each list item?

Like:

1. Example 1
2. Example 2
3. Example 3

If so, make sure your ol has this css:

```
ol { list-style: decimal; }
```